# Stability issues while using solr cloud

Tags: solr, solrcloud

We are using solr cloud 6.3 with 16 servers set up with 5 Zookeeper nodes quorum. Here are config stats

```
solr version 6.3
lucene 6.3
java version 8
Processors 32
RAM 32 GB
SSD drives worth 100 GB
```

On this 16 machines set up we have 2 collections. Solr itself is taking care of routing documents, we are not using custom sharding.
On 4 of 16 machines, there is one collection, collection "**A**", that has 1.1 million documents divided into 2 shards. Each shard has two replica and there is a single core on each machine.
On 12 of 16 machines, there is another collection, collection "**B**", that has 9 million documents divided into 3 shards. Each shard has 4 replicas and there is single core on each machine.

For collection "**A**" Here is solrconfig

```
<luceneMatchVersion>6.3.0</luceneMatchVersion>
<directoryFactory name="DirectoryFactory"
               class="${solr.directoryFactory:solr.MMapDirectoryFactory}"/>
  <indexConfig>
    <useCompoundFile>false</useCompoundFile>
    <maxIndexingThreads>10</maxIndexingThreads>
     <mergePolicyFactory class="org.apache.solr.index.TieredMergePolicyFactory">
          <int name="maxMergeAtOnce">2147483647</int>
          <int name="segmentsPerTier">2</int>
     </mergePolicyFactory>
    <ramBufferSizeMB>1000</ramBufferSizeMB>
    <maxBufferedDocs>1000</maxBufferedDocs>
    <filter class="solr.LimitTokenCountFilterFactory" maxTokenCount="10000"/>
    <writeLockTimeout>1000</writeLockTimeout>
    <commitLockTimeout>10000</commitLockTimeout>
    <lockType>native</lockType>
  </indexConfig>
<updateHandler class="solr.DirectUpdateHandler2">
    <maxPendingDeletes>100000</maxPendingDeletes>
    <updateLog>
         <int name="numRecordsToKeep">200</int>
         <int name="maxNumLogsToKeep">5</int>
    </updateLog>
    <autoCommit>
        <maxDocs>500</maxDocs>
        <maxTime>120000</maxTime>
        <openSearcher>false</openSearcher>
     </autoCommit>
     <autoSoftCommit>
         <maxDocs>300</maxDocs>
         <maxTime>60000</maxTime>
      </autoSoftCommit>
</updateHandler>
```

For collection "**B**, Here is the solrconfig

```
<luceneMatchVersion>6.3.0</luceneMatchVersion>
<directoryFactory name="DirectoryFactory"
               class="${solr.directoryFactory:solr.MMapDirectoryFactory}"/>
<codecFactory class="solr.SchemaCodecFactory"/>
 <indexConfig>
    <useCompoundFile>false</useCompoundFile>
    <maxIndexingThreads>10</maxIndexingThreads>
    <ramBufferSizeMB>1000</ramBufferSizeMB>
    <maxBufferedDocs>1000</maxBufferedDocs>
    <filter class="solr.LimitTokenCountFilterFactory" maxTokenCount="10000"/>
    <writeLockTimeout>5000</writeLockTimeout>
    <commitLockTimeout>10000</commitLockTimeout>
    <lockType>native</lockType>
    <mergePolicyFactory class="org.apache.solr.index.TieredMergePolicyFactory">
          <int name="maxMergeAtOnce">6</int>
          <int name="segmentsPerTier">6</int>
     </mergePolicyFactory>
 </indexConfig>
<updateHandler class="solr.DirectUpdateHandler2">
    <maxPendingDeletes>100000</maxPendingDeletes>
    <updateLog>
         <int name="numRecordsToKeep">200</int>
         <int name="maxNumLogsToKeep">5</int>
    </updateLog>
    <autoCommit>
        <maxDocs>500</maxDocs>
        <maxTime>120000</maxTime>
        <openSearcher>false</openSearcher>
     </autoCommit>
     <autoSoftCommit>
         <maxDocs>300</maxDocs>
         <maxTime>60000</maxTime>
      </autoSoftCommit>
</updateHandler>
```

We are facing below problems with this set up:

1. Long pauses while using G1GC.
2. Once in every 24 hours 4 or 5 machines of this cluster get a spike of read/write, load average, memory and CPU.

We have a load of 20k requests per minutes on this cluster. 
6k requests for collection **A** and 14k request for core **B**.

**Update**:
[Heap usage graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XO757.png)

Comment: More information will be needed :
- How the java processes look like ? memory allocated to the JVM vs memory allocated to the OS ?
- What about indexing ? Does this happen during searches ?
- is any event happening every 24 hours ? Is the spike happening regularly ?

Comment: Total RAM on each machine - 32 GB, Allocated to JVM-7GB. Our indexing job runs every 20 seconds and creates approximately 90-100 documents on an average. We are indexing data through zookeeper. Search requests directly come on solr machines. There is no event happening during this duration. yes, the spike has become regular now, every 24 hours it occurs 4-5 times in a day and will remain until restart of solr is taken. after restart it becomes normal.

Comment: Long GC pauses could derive from an excess in heap memory allocation.
How did you work out the 7 GB ?
I would start from that, evaluating the actual memory needs per node ( this article may help [1]).
Quick points to cover :
1) do you use docValues for fields you facet/sort on ? This should relieve pressure on the heap 
2) I saw in the past Solr nodes used both for indexing and searching, to be polluted a lot memory-wise, but I would need to investigate the exact scenarios

[1] https://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2017/06/apache-solr-memory-tuning-for-production/

Comment: 1) We are using sorting mostly on dates and int values with docValues enabled. For facet, we are using string fields but we are not using docValues with them.  2)  Heap size of 7 GB was decided because we are using filtercache of size 1024. Each entry can be upto 2.5 MB resulting into 1024*2.5 MB = 2.56GB. Whatever queries we have they are mostly using facet and sorting  so 7GB sought to be a good number. Attaching a graph which will show the heap usage.We have utilization of approx 6 Gb heap most of the time.